# scrapy create yield field dynamically with a variable

Tags: python, scrapy

I want go get all bullet points with scrapy from an amazon product page e.g. [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K3JD7RF), however their number varies. I end up using something like this

```
def parse(self, response):
        t = response
        url = t.request.url
        yield{
                'bullets_no': len(t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()'))
                'bullet_1' : t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()')[0].get().strip()
                'bullet_2' : t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()')[1].get().strip()
                'bullet_3' : t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()')[2].get().strip()
                'bullet_4' : t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()')[3].get().strip()
                'bullet_5' : t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()')[4].get().strip()
...
            }
```

however in pythong i would be able to simply do something like this and adjust automatically:

```
bullets = t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()')
    for i, bullet in enumerate(bullets):
        row[f'Bullet_{i+1}'] = bullet.strip()
```

Is it possible to create yielded fields like this in scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is covered in detail in the [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) which I highly suggest reading.

The return type when using either the `response.css` or `response.xpath` calls is a `SelectorList` object. You can iterate this object like you can a regular python `list` object.

> The result of running response.css('title') is a list-like object called SelectorList, which represents a list of Selector objects that wrap around XML/HTML elements and allow you to run further queries to fine-grain the selection or extract the data.

So using your example you could do something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = {'url': response.url}
    for i, bullet in enumerate(response.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()'), start=1):
        item[f'bullet_{i}'] = bullet.get().strip()
    item['bullet_no'] = i
    yield item
```

As mention in a previous answer there is also the `getall` method that you can call on a selector list:

> The other thing is that the result of calling .getall() is a list: it is possible that a selector returns more than one result, so we extract them all.

I suggest giving the [Extracting Data](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data) and [Extracting Quotes and Authors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-quotes-and-authors) sections of the scrapy docs tutorial a read to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getall()` in this case you will get list

```
def parse(self, response):
    t = response
    url = t.request.url
    yield{f"bullet_{i}": el.strip() for i, el in enumerate(t.xpath('//div[@id="feature-bullets"]//li/span/text()').getall(), start=1) }
```